# Need help using this API to show information (Ionic 3)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest this is my API. In my .ts I'm doing

```
this.currencyProvider.GetCurrencyData().subscribe((data) =>{
      this.currency=data.rates
    });
```

and so does that mean that in my HTML I just have to do something like 
     {{currency.USD}}
 or is it something else? When I've done this nothing even shows up on the page when I run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for you :

In Component:

```
public currency; 
this.currencyProvider.GetCurrencyData().subscribe((data:any) =>{
   this.currency=data.rates;
});
```

In Html:

```
<div>
{{currency?.USD}}
</div>
```

Working demo : [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/currencyrate?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.html)